# Bootstrap button width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following screenshot is the result of thew below code:
https://gyazo.com/e7ad0eb6fe40ad6362a1290d4b740a39

I'm trying to create four equal width buttons.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                            <button id="slct" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Bridge</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                            <button id="slct" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Container</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                            <button id="slct" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cylinders</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                        <button id="slct" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Fence</button>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: I just copy paste your code, it looks fine?  https://plnkr.co/edit/m7hN2pygjL5YxnzL7r5g?p=preview

Comment: In your screenshot, I believe that you have other styles that are conflicting /overriding with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom css file and build on top of the bootstrap css. So create a new css file, and then have btn btn-default class a set width.

```
.btn btn-default {min-width:YourSize;}
```

Comment: Better would be to declare a specific class for the specific width, rather than hijack all `btn-default` buttons.  Example: `.btn-mywidth` for example, then add it to the markup `<button class="btn btn-default btn-mywidth">`

Comment: I agree with @cale_b's solution as a safer method.